# Use alert from ng-click of a directive

Tags: angularjs

New to angularjs.
Want to write an expression into an ng-click.

example:

```
x.directive('li',function(){
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true, 
      template: '<games> <game  ng-click="(alert({{ game }})" ng-repeat="game in games"> {{ game.team1 }} {{game.bets }}   <game></br></games> '
  }     
});
```

I want to alert the game on click but I got this error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'game' is unexpected, expecting [:] at column 11 of the expression [(alert({{ game }})] starting at [game }})].
```

Comment: try ng-click="console.log(game)"

Comment: didn't work out @HarishR

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When you ask for 'alert' from ng-click, it looks for that method on the $scope, and it's not there.

See this [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4wcO5NoliuM9eKXcVNFA?p=preview) where I used a function on the scope to call the alert when the directive is clicked.

In the controller we set the function:

```
$scope.test = function(text) {
  alert(text);
}
```

Or you can just do: `$scope.alert = alert.bind(window);`. It won't work without binding the context to the window if you do it like that.

In the directive's ng-click we call our function:

```
 ng-click="test(game)"
```

Comment: the alert actually does work, when you click on the text 'test' (which is where the ng-click is placed'

Comment: +1 for your time but this is not what I've asked for.

Comment: please clarify what you need. you want to alert a variable with ng-click from your template, your template is working fine. you need to remove the curly-braces, and I recommend creating a function to perform the alert, and just call the function from the template's ng-click, like in the plunkr. review the plunkr please and ask if something isn't clear

Comment: I want to output the "game in games" from the view with ng-click without the controller. Basically I want to to do this: ng-click="(alert({{some expression }})"

Comment: Or just have a function called 'alert' on the controller $scope. Then you can use alert() in the html as expected