# function call in ng-repeat does not render properly

Tags: angularjs

I have this piece of code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="convention in conventions">
            <td>{{ convention.Id }}</td>
            <td>{{ convention.Title }}</td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="alert(convention.Id)">Edit</a></td>
        </tr>
```

I wanna call a function like `alert` and pass `Id` as parameter.but It does not render properly:
[image: firbug]

any suggestion?

Comment: `ng-click="javascript:alert(convention.Id)"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use alert from ng-click of a directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907383/use-alert-from-ng-click-of-a-directive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the `alert()` in a function in your controller and add it to the scope like this:

```
$scope.handleClick = function(id) {
    alert(id);
}
```

Then call this function from the template:

```
ng-click="handleClick(contention.Id)"
```

Expressions embedded in your templates do only see the functions in the respective scope.

Answer (score 2):

Add `alert` to your scope, like so in your controller

```
$scope.alert = function(i) {
  alert(i)
};
```