# how can i get 2 functions in one ng-click?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I want to get 2 functions in one ng-click. 
Here is the code:

```
<button class="cButtonSpeichern" ng-click="saveUser()">Speichern</button>
```

and i want to add this function.

```
alert()
```

can someone help me?

Comment: call another method inside saveUser()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a method like the following:

```
function onSpeichernClick() {
    saveUser();
    alert();
}
```

**Usage**

```
<button class="cButtonSpeichern" ng-click="onSpeichernClick()">Speichern</button>
```

Comment: This is important because down the line you may change the logic of what happens when you click that button. All the layout needs to know is to call the onSpeichernClick() method and you can control what happens inside of it without ever changing the layout.

Comment: did it work, when i make it like this?
    <button class="cButtonSpeichern" ng-click="saveUser();alert()">Speichern</button>

Answer (score 2):

@Joopkins answer is best but:

```
<button class="cButtonSpeichern" ng-click="saveUser();alert()">Speichern</button>
```

should also work if you don't have access to the controller.

Comment: alert() is not working for ng-click, tried in jsfiddle. Might be alert is getting referenced as $scope.alert().

Comment: See this one...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907383/use-alert-from-ng-click-of-a-directive
Its better to call only scope functions for ng-click

Answer (score 0):

You can do two things:

1. have a function like 'onButtonClick' that is responsible for calling the two functions.

In your html:

```
<button class="cButtonSpeichern" ng-click="onButtonClick()">Speichern</button>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.onButtonClick = function(){
  callFunction1();  //in your case saveUser()
  callFunction2();  //in you case alert()
}
```

2. call both of them from the event binding in the button

   ```
   <button class="cButtonSpeichern" ng-click="saveUser(); alert()">Speichern</button>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert() will not work from ng-click
```

[Use alert from ng-click of a directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25907383/use-alert-from-ng-click-of-a-directive)

Its better to call a function of scope for ng-click and the call your actual two functions from inside that scope function like @Joopkins answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try Joopkins' Solution or simply do

```
<button class="cButtonSpeichern" ng-click="saveUser();showalert()">Speichern</button>
```

and

```
function showalert(){
   alert('Your Message');
}
```

the reason behind this usage is that you cannot call javascript functions directly using ng-click

check this Demo:
http://learnkode.com/try/f6FqCfZa